# Intersection of open balls

Tags: real-analysis

$(X,\|.\|)$ a normed space and $d(x,y) = \|{x-y}\|,~ x,y \in X, \varepsilon > 0,
 (X,d), $ a metric space. $$B(x,\varepsilon)=\{y\in X \mid d(x,y) < \varepsilon \}$$
$$ B(0,\varepsilon)=\{y\in X \mid d(0,y) < \varepsilon \}$$ open balls. What is the relation between these 2 sets?

I don't understand the question. I mean I am trying to apply restrictions on $x$ and $\varepsilon$ so the balls intersect but I'm having no luck.

\begin{align*}
d^2(x,y)=\|{x-y}\|^2 &= \langle x-y,x-y \rangle \\ &= \langle x-y,x\rangle + \langle x-y,y \rangle \\ &= \langle x,x \rangle -  \langle y,x \rangle -\langle x,y \rangle + \langle y,y \rangle  \\&= \langle x,x \rangle - 2\langle x,y \rangle + \langle y,y \rangle < \varepsilon^2 \quad  \\
d^2(0,y)=\|{y}\|^2 &= \langle y,y \rangle  < \varepsilon^2 \quad 
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
d^2(x,y)+d^2(0,y)=\|{x-y}\|^2+\|{y}\|^2&= \langle x,x \rangle - 2\langle x,y \rangle + \langle y,y \rangle + \langle y,y \rangle \\&= \|{x}\|^2+\|{y}\|^2-2\langle x,y \rangle < 2\varepsilon^2 \end{align*}
This feels like it's not leading anywhere, any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the question? Relation between 2 sets is very broad.

Comment: This is exactly the question from my problem set, which is why I'm so confused. I assume it's intersection and union of the two sets.

Comment: We can only say that $B(x,\epsilon) = x + B(0,\epsilon)$.

Comment: Is there no ways to restrict $x$ so that $B(x,\epsilon) \cap B(0,\epsilon) \neq \emptyset$?

Comment: If we are going to go with intersections, we can say that if $\epsilon < ||x||/2$, then $B(0,\epsilon)\cap B(x,\epsilon)$ is empty. Would that be relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $X$ is a normed linear space and $e>0$ then $B(x,e)\cap B(0,e)\ne \phi$ iff $\|x\|<2e.$ Sufficiency: If $\|x\|<2e$ then $x/2\in B(x,e)\cap B(0,e).$ Necessity: If  $y\in B(x,e)\cap B(0,e)$ then $\|x\|=\|(x-y)+y\|\leq \|x-y\|+\|y\|<e+\|y\|<2e.$

When $e>0$  the only condition that can guarantee $\phi\ne B(x,e)\cap B(x',e)$ for all metric spaces is $x=x'.$ For example if $d(x,x')=42$ whenever $x\ne x'$ then $B(x,e)=\{x\}$ whenever $e\leq 42.$

For Q's about normed linear spaces it's often useful to first consider the spaces $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$ and consider the Q  geometrically: Two open discs in a plane, with radii $r_1$ and $r_2$, intersect iff the distance between their centers is less than $r_1+r_2.$